# opencv - c++: how i use fastNlMeansDenoisingColoredMulti()

Tags: c++, opencv, video

I have a video (130 frames). when I run my code my result is a line instead of an image so I guess I do not use fastNlMeansDenoisingColoredMulti function correctly. What should I do?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    VideoCapture video("F:\\tarashi\\datasets\\video\\1.mp4");
    if (!video.isOpened())
    {
        cout << "Error opening video stream or file" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    namedWindow("test video", 1);
    int i = 0;
    Mat image[130];
    for (;i<130;i=i+1)
    {
        Mat frame;
        video >> frame; // get a new frame from camera   
        image[i] = frame;
        imshow("test video", frame);

        if (waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
    //Video opened and the image sequence is created.

    Mat result;
    fastNlMeansDenoisingColoredMulti(image[129],result,65,129,3,3,7,21);
    imshow("denoised Image", result);
    waitKey();
    return 0;
    }
```

Example: This is a screenshot of the video:
[image]
So expecting a full picture to output. but My output(result) is :[image]

Comment: Out of range, must be: fastNlMeansDenoisingColoredMulti(image[129]...

Comment: @Nuzhny I do not have that error now, but I do not have the correct output yet. I just have a line instead of an image.

Comment: But I don't know about expected result. What do you want? Your question was about error - this problem was solved.

Comment: @Nuzhny I put the output image that you see the hidden error. I ask how use fastNlMeansDenoisingColoredMulti() correctly and I didn't get my answer so this problem isn't solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> fastNlMeansDenoisingColoredMulti( InputArrayOfArrays srcImgs,
>   OutputArray dst,
>           int imgToDenoiseIndex, int temporalWindowSize,
>           float h = 3, float hColor = 3,
>           int templateWindowSize = 7, int searchWindowSize = 21);

*InputArrayOfArrays srcImgs* - array of images, but you put only one frame.
Try this:

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> images;
...
images.push_back(frame);
...
fastNlMeansDenoisingColoredMulti(images, ...
```